# Is argument not null

Tags: ant

I am trying to check the ant build script's argument is set or not. I have tried many way to do this but there is no success. I define the argument with `-Dmaindir="../propertyfolderpath"`.

Here is the code sample that I  have tried;

```
<ac:if>
    <equals arg1="@{maindir}" arg2="" />
    <ac:then>
        <echo message="maindir argument is empty. Current properties will be used." />
        <property file="build.properties" />
    </ac:then>
    <ac:else>
        <echo message="maindir = ${maindir}" />
        <ac:if>
            <ac:available file="${maindir}/build.properties" type="file" />
            <ac:then>
                <property file="${maindir}/build.properties" />
            </ac:then>
            <ac:else>
                <fail message="${maindir} is not a valid path." />
            </ac:else>
        </ac:if>
    </ac:else>  
</ac:if>
```

- There are three cases;

  1. Argument might not be defined. Ant should go into first
  2. Argument defined well.
  3. Argument defined with wrong path

For 2nd case script is working.
For 3rd case script is working.
But for 1st case, I mean when I dont define maindir argument, ant act like 3rd case. That is my problem.

Why ant act like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try setting a default value for the argument?

```
<condition property="maindir" value="[default]">
    <not>  
        <isset property="maindir"/>
    </not>
</condition>
<echo message="${maindir}" />
```

I tried this and it works, when no argument is passed the value of `${maindir}` is `[default]`.

Comment: I suggest `[default]` will become `${basedir}`

Comment: thx. This works for me too. Both Laepdjek's and your answers are correct. I used both answers. Thx. And Arne you right. I have already used it like '${basedir}`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are two problems:

1. In the equals condition for the first if, you have `@{maindir}`. Unless it is a parameter to a macro, this should be `${maindir}` instead, the same as in the rest of your example
2. If a property hasn't been set, it will not be evaluated to anything. So if maindir is not defined, `${maindir}` will evaluate to `${maindir}`, and not to the empty string.

The easiest way to solve this is to change the @ sign to a $ sign, and add a statement at the beginning to default the property to a value:

```
<property name="maindir" value="." />
```

This will default the property to the current directory, and so you could completely eliminate the outer if, since it would no longer be needed. Properties in ant are readonly, so if the user explicitly specifies a value (e.g. from the command line), that value will be used instead, and the above line won't have any effect - it will only have an effect if the user didn't specify a value for maindir.

In fact, I think you could get rid of ant-contrib entirely by doing the following:

```
<property name="maindir" value="." />
<fail message="${maindir}/build.properties is not a valid path.">
    <condition>
        <not>
            <available file="${maindir}/build.properties" />
        </not>
    </condition>
</fail>
<property file="${maindir}/build.properties" />
```

That should have the exact same effect as what you were looking to achieve with your example.

Comment: Thx Laepdjek . This works for me as I mention on  my comment  on Alex's answer.